# Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 192.168.65.1:3128

Tags: docker, tcp, grafana, daemon

> docker run -d --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana-enterprise:9.2.0 Unable to find image 'grafana/grafana-enterprise:9.2.0' locally docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 192.168.65.1:3128: connect: connection refused.

How to solve this? https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/  the image when tried to access from browser

[image]

I was trying to implement Grafana in Docker by following [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/docker/).

Comment: Are you running docker in windows or linux? The 3128 port appears to be an HTTP proxy, are you behind a corporate proxy? If so, do you need it?

Comment: yes.I am behind a corporate proxy wifi network.And my docker is running in Windows with the help of WSL.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you have an internal proxy you need to connect through. You may be able to solve it using the HTTP PROXY instructions for docker: `https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/`

Comment: {
  "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\snyk.exe"
}                     this is the only content available in that config.json as of now.             
     Where can I add the below thing?    Was this valid for all the geolocation ? what should I give in place of "    test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8 "  ?
   }
 }               
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "httpsProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8"
   }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

After you provided the image I can saw that your corporate proxy is requesting authentication. So, your docker is stopping on this connection step.

Ps.: Proxies are different, so it's important to check with your OPS team which kind of authentication your proxy expects.
Anyways, try those steps separately testing again after each one

1. Configure HTTP(S)_PROXY env variables

Configure HTTP_PROXY and/or HTTPS_PROXY env variables in your WSL like that:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@hostname:port
export $http_proxy
```

and/or

```
https_proxy=http://username:password@hostname:port
export $https_proxy
```

Where username and password are to authenticate in proxy and hostname and port are proxy DNS name/IP and (probably) port 3128 as I noticed in your logs

2. Configure Docker desktop proxy https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/
3. In case your proxy is requiring NTLM authentication, you might have more issues. I would say you will need to try something like that > https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121521/how-to-configure-http-proxy-with-authentication-on-ubuntu-wsl-on-windows-10

*Workaround: Before doing any suggested steps, you can try to pull the docker image using private internet access such as a 4G or your home wifi. It will isolate your problem from the proxy thing*

Comment: Thank you all for your help.Uninstalled and reinstalled the docker .Then signed in docker with docker hub account after emailID verification within dockerhub.  I have connected to PC via LAN cable of office network . Then executed docker run -d --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana-enterprise:9.2.0    .it got executed without showing the proxy issues.  Also try to stop the standalone Grafana(if any) in windows which is listening to the same port via Services of windows.